# identify onboard AMD GPU

Tags: ubuntu, amd-graphics

I'm trying to identify AMD graphics card between onboard and dedicated GPU.

using `sudo find /sys/devices | grep pp_dpm_mclk` I was able to find information regarding AMD graphics card.

now that I have those information, how do I know which is the onboard GPU? thank you for any suggestions / pointer

(edited)
here's the lspci | grep VGA

```
00:01.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Device 98e4 (rev 81)
07:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Device 67df (rev c7)
09:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Device 67df (rev e7)
```

Comment: please add the output of `lspci | grep VGA` to your question.

Comment: just added the information

Comment: Device id's are registered and published, a search for pci id 98e4 got me to [this page](https://developer.amd.com/resources/ati-catalyst-pc-vendor-id-1002-li/), which says 67df is your rx480.

Comment: the GPU in the lowest numbered PCI "slot" is usually (almost always) the built-in GPU.  `00:01.0` in this case.   looking up the device id and revision (98e4 rev81), it's an AMD Radeon™ R4E Graphics adapter.    The other two seem to be an RX 480 and an RX 580.

Comment: great information! thank you! using device ID is sure a good way! BUT, what if I want to avoid looking up information on internet, is there other ways?

Comment: i guess you could memorise all the device codes and revisions for all GPU manufacturers.  or compile a list.  more seriously, as I mentioned, the GPU in the lowest numbered PCI slot is almost certainly the on-board GPU.   Try it and see.  If it isn't, move on to the next.  repeat until you've found it.

Comment: the lowest number seems to be true, however, some system I will be working with will not have onboard GPU, =( I guess compiling a list might be my choice for now

Comment: the list could be a lot shorter if you only bother memorising what GPUs you bought and which slot you installed them in (and on which system) :)  i.e. this seems to be more of an asset management issue than a tech issue.

Comment: that's true, however, the software will be installed in unknown amount and type of system, unfortunately =(

Comment: @jthill you may as well make that into an answer. Alternatively, Jim, if Jthil doesn't want to, please expand their comment into an answer yourself and post it. Mods cannot convert comments into answers.

Comment: `hwinfo --gfxcard` should resolve the issue for you.

Comment: @terdon doesn't make sense to me that it wouldn't show up on the lspci, mine shows my 1060/3GB and I didn't want to put more effort into that.  OP, are you running some ultra-stable distro like centos or debian stable that only updates for actual bugs between major releases?  Maybe that would explain why the `pci.ids` file on your system isn't more up to date.

Comment: The OP asked to convert your comment into an answer claiming that it was "the answer". That's why I asked. I don't have an opinion one way or the other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Device id's are registered and published, a search for pci id 98e4 got me to [this page](https://developer.amd.com/resources/ati-catalyst-pc-vendor-id-1002-li/), which says 67df/c7  is your rx480.

That page doesn't look like it's as well-maintained as its prominence on the search results suggests. I think lshw/lspci/hwinfo all use a `pci.ids` file maintained collaboratively by volunteers, if you're using one of the stability-uber-alles distros, debian stable or rhel or centos maybe, I guess that file could be far enough out of date that those id's aren't registered yet.